# Getting error in url from HTML template to urls. No reverse match

Tags: django, django-views, django-urls

I am trying to delete a record the on basis of primary key, so I am trying to pass a PK to url into a view function but getting this error:

django.urls.exceptions.NoReverseMatch:

```
 Reverse for 'delete_view' with arguments '('',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['essay/(?P<essay_id>[0-9]+)/delEssay/$']
```

My html code:

```
  <form method="POST" action="{% url 'essay:delete_view' teacher.id %}">
     <div class="page-header">
      <div class="span4">
        <h1>Manage Essays</h1>
      </div>
  </div>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th>Title</th>
            <th>Edit</th>
            <th>Delete</th>
        </tr>
      {% csrf_token %}
        {% for uploadassignment in teacher.uploadassignment_set.all %}
         <tr>
             <th for="uploadassignment{{ forloop.counter }}">{{uploadassignment.title}}</th>
             <th><input  type="submit" value="Edit" class="btn btn-primary"/></th>
             <th><input type="submit" value="Delete" name="delEssay" id="delEssay" class="btn btn-primary"/></th>
         </tr>
        {% endfor %}
    </table>
        </form>
```

URL:

```
      url(r'^(?P<essay_id>[0-9]+)/delEssay/$', views.delete_view, name='delete_view')
```

View Function:

```
def delete_view(request,essay_id):
 print("Delete")
 print(essay_id)
 object = UploadAssignment.objects.get(id=essay_id)
 object.delete()
 return render(request, 'essay/THome.html')
```

Comment: Likely the `teacher` variable does not exist at all in the template, since `teacher.id` is invalid.

Comment: https://www.reddit.com/r/django/comments/7lt2v4/reverse_for_with_no_arguments_not_found_1/

Comment: In your template try using `{%... essay_id=teacher.id%}` instead of `{%... teacher.id%}`

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to access the object ID `teacher.id`, instead you try with primary key pk like `teacher.pk`

I had the same problem and i replaced it with pk and it worked.

hope this solves your problem.